# show dimension of flv in text field

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flv, flvplayback

Below is my basic code, im loading a flv video using flvplayback.

i need the features of flvplayback compulsorily.

I have finished loading flv video sucessfully.

Now im stuckup with showing the source video files original dimension in a text field.

How should proceed further from here. Please guide me......

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

import fl.video.*;

stop();

var rmys01:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
rmys01.source = "rhym01.flv";
rmys01.skin = "MinimaFlatCustomColorPlayBackSeekCounterVolMute.swf";
rmys01.autoPlay = true;
rmys01.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
rmys01.scaleMode = "maintainAspectRatio";
rmys01.setSize((stage.stageWidth/1.03), (stage.stageHeight/1.03));
rmys01.x = (stage.stageWidth/2)  - (rmys01.width/2);
rmys01.y = (stage.stageHeight/1.1) - (rmys01.height/1.1);
addChild(rmys01);
setChildIndex(rmys01,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set client for the NetStream? Because, all work ok.

Here is an example:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
var client: Object = {};
client.onMetaData = function(data:Object):void{
    //Display width and height
    var textField: TextField = new TextField();
    textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 28);
    textField.text = "Width: " + data.width + ", Height: " + data.height;
    addChild(textField);
}
ns.client = client;
ns.play("path/to/Video");

var myVideo:Video = new Video();
myVideo.attachNetStream(ns);
addChild(myVideo);
```

For debugging purposes place trace (`trace("There is MetaData!");`) to the onMetaData handler, check, if it triggers.

For FLVPlayback, you should subscribe for [VideoEvent.READY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event%3aready):

```
rmys01.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, onReady);

function onReady(e:VideoEvent):void {
    trace("READY");
    var flvPlayback:FLVPlayback = e.target as FLVPlayback;
    var metaData:Object = flvPlayback.metadata as Object;
    trace("height: "+metaData.height);
    trace("width: "+metaData.width);
    trace("duration: "+metaData.duration);
}
```

If you are coding in Flash IDE, there will be a problem with VideoEvent, so you should use fully qualified class (`fl.video.VideoEvent`), if not, IDE will try resolve it to the `flash.events.VideoEvent`:

```
rmys01.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.READY, onReady);

function onReady(e:fl.video.VideoEvent):void {
    //Handler code
}
```

Comment: FLVPlayback? Did you try to subscribe to the `VideoEvent.READY` event?   And in the event extract metadata. `var metaData:Object = rmys01.metadata as Object;`

Comment: I have added FLVPlayback example.

Comment: The code you gave showed error 1119 with VideoEvent.READY

Comment: Did you import VideoEvent?

Comment: yes i did

import fl.video.VideoEvent;

please explain in detail in my new answer section. Thanks